# Delete dimension in a netcdf file using python

Tags: python, netcdf, dimension, imshow

I have a netcdf file with 4 variables (ssh,sst,ssu and ssv) and 3 dimensions : time(34),latitude(208) and longitude (176). I want to delete the time to be able to plot the variables with imshow . Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete the time'?  With that shape you have values at 34 different times.  Do you want to pick one time, such as the last?  average values over all times?  or something else.  Once  you have loaded a variable into memory, it is a `numpy` array, which can be manipulated in many ways.  You don't want to change the data that's on the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options (select some time-moments, average for certain periods, use some tools like cdo or nco, etc), but most likely you either want to plot certain timestep (for instance the first timestep):

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
ncin=Dataset(ncfilename);
sshdata=np.squeeze(ncin.variables['ssh'][0,:,:])
ncin.close()
```

or you can make some averages (for instance averaging over the time):

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
ncin=Dataset(ncfilename);
sshdata=np.squeeze(np.mean(ncin.variables['ssh'][:],axis=0))
ncin.close()
```

In either case, the variable sshdata is supposed to have 2 dimensions: lat and lon.

Comment: Can I store them in seperate 2d arrays ? Actually I  want to reduce the dimensions of lat/lon via pca .

Comment: What do you want to save? If you want to perform PCA on your data, you should look for some examples or tools.

Comment: My data's shape is (34,303,449) and I want to work with 64*64 images . Is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible - you can cut the data as you see fit - but question is what do you want to do exactly. Perhaps you should edit the question accordingly or if it is completely different from original question, ask another question.